# Posts with only ansible tag has no syntax highlighting

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

There is no syntax highlighting in posts for only [ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansible) tag, it looks so poor to read unless you add [yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yaml) tag or language directive. I think this should be solved

Comment: Case in point: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68120849) is currently tagged with Ansible but there's no syntax highlighting. That said, do you have any proposal as to what language should the highlighter choose as the default? [The tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ansible/info) mentioned several languages like Python, YAML, JSON. Also to be noted, if a question has 2 or more tags with different syntax highlighting (e.g. 'python' and 'ansible'), then the system will fall back to a more general syntax highlighting that may be non-ideal.

Comment: I agree with @AndrewT., I don't think there's one default syntax we should have for this tag. You can configure it and run scripts with YAML, it uses JSON for communication, most modules are written in Python, and there are wrappers or interfaces in a number of other languages like PHP, JS, Ruby, Java, Go, etc. Language-neutral is the way to go with this tag.

Comment: Well, examples in the documentation are in yaml. It would make absolute sense to make yaml default. Whatever I've googled about ansible, SO pops up but the posts have very poor readability without any syntax highlighting. What do you think?